# Types of tofu that can be used in a crock pot

Tags: slow-cooking, tofu

I am currently trying to get rid of some firm and soft tofu that's been in my fridge for a while, and I wanted to try out a few slow cooker recipes for braised tofu. However, all of these recipes call for extra-firm tofu.

Would less firm tofu be able to hold up to 6+ hours of crock pot cooking? Or is it really critical that I use extra-firm tofu for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of variance in tofu, but there's usually a significant difference between firm and extra firm. The soft tofu will not hold up, it will probably dissolve after 6 hours. The firm tofu may possibly hold up, it really depends on how firm the brand makes their firm tofu, I suggest you try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I have used all types of tofu in a crock pot. There is no need to use firm tofu so long as you don't stir. Neither is there boiling to disturb the soft or silken tofu, but you have to be more careful ladling it out. Having said that, firm tofu is often the type to use for braising.